# Fix t-junction in mesh

Tags: python, mesh, bmesh

I'm currently modifying a mesh using a Python script. I just realised that my mesh have a few t-junctions, which I would like to fix. Is there any way to fix t-junctions in Blender? If so, is it also possible to do this from script?

Clarification: My mesh contains t-junctions where the vertices are disconnected from the opposite face. A script or Blender feature that just 'glues'/connects the vertex would also work fine for me.

[image]

Comment: see if this helps [T-Junction-remover](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?81516-T-Junction-remover)

Comment: The script is quite old and doesn't run on the current Blender version. I was hoping to find some off-the-shelf solution that worked out of the box. (If not, I have a few ideas of how to make such script myself)

Answer (score 3):

I came up with the solution below, which seems to work. Generally I just create faces in the holes (the black on the figure above) and finally dissolve degenerate (since the newly introduced faced has the area of zero).

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from math import radians, degrees, pi, atan2
from mathutils import Vector, Euler

def isEdgesOverlapping(v, e1, e2):
    if e1 == e2:
        return False
    v0 = v.co
    v1 = None
    v2 = None
    if (e1.verts[0] == v):
        v1 = e1.verts[1].co
    else:
        v1 = e1.verts[0].co
    if (e2.verts[0] == v):
        v2 = e2.verts[1].co
    else:
        v2 = e2.verts[0].co
    dir1 = (v1 - v0).normalized()
    dir2 = (v2 - v0).normalized()
    if dir1.cross(dir2) < 0.00001 and dir1.dot(dir2) > 0.5:
        return True
    return False


def fixTJunctions2(bm): 
    for e in bm.edges:
        e.select = False
    for v in bm.verts:
            for e1 in v.link_edges:
                for e2 in v.link_edges:
                    if isEdgesOverlapping(v, e1, e2):
                        e1.select = True
                        e2.select = True
                        bpy.ops.mesh.edge_face_add()
                        return True
    return False   

def fixTJunctions(obj):
    if bpy.context.mode == 'OBJECT':
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT', toggle=True)
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    for e in bm.edges:
        e.select = False    
    continueLoop = True 
    count = 0
    while continueLoop:
        bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
        bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()
        bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
        continueLoop = fixTJunctions2(bm)
        count = count + 1
    if count > 1:
        bpy.ops.mesh.dissolve_degenerate()

obj = bpy.context.active_object 
fixTJunctions(obj)
```